# Flash Decompiler

Tags: flash

Anyone have experience with flash decompilers? What are some of the best products out there?

Answer (score 5):

there is also [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SWF Decompiler for Windows](http://www.flash-decompiler.com/). There was another one from ages ago called SWF2FLA, but I don't know if that's still around, or if in fact it's the one I'm linking to.

Answer (score 2):

Also Aspose.Flash for .NET component can do some decompilation.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Action Script Viewer www.buraks.com/asv, Windows only, first Flash/SWF decompiler.

Another Windows only solution that just shows AS3 scripts is [AS3 Sorcerer](http://www.buraks.com/asv/).

And yes, I work for the company that makes these software.